# Jackson deserialize object or array

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a Jackson Question.

Is there a way to deserialize a property that may have two types, for some objects it appears like this

```
"someObj" : { "obj1" : 5, etc....}
```

then for others it appears as an empty array, i.e.

```
"someObj" : []
```

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39041496/how-to-enforce-accept-single-value-as-array-in-jacksons-deserialization-process#answer-39043513) answer useful if you want to do this on a single property

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Jackson doesn't currently have a built-in configuration to automatically handle this particular case, so custom deserialization processing is necessary.

Following is an example of what such custom deserialization might look like.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonProcessingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.Version;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect.Visibility;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonMethod;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationContext;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonDeserializer;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.module.SimpleModule;

public class JacksonFoo
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    // {"property1":{"property2":42}}
    String json1 = "{\"property1\":{\"property2\":42}}";

    // {"property1":[]}
    String json2 = "{\"property1\":[]}";

    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("", Version.unknownVersion());
    module.addDeserializer(Thing2.class, new ArrayAsNullDeserializer());

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().setVisibility(JsonMethod.FIELD, Visibility.ANY).withModule(module);

    Thing1 firstThing = mapper.readValue(json1, Thing1.class);
    System.out.println(firstThing);
    // output:
    // Thing1: property1=Thing2: property2=42

    Thing1 secondThing = mapper.readValue(json2, Thing1.class);
    System.out.println(secondThing);
    // output: 
    // Thing1: property1=null
  }
}

class Thing1
{
  Thing2 property1;

  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    return String.format("Thing1: property1=%s", property1);
  }
}

class Thing2
{
  int property2;

  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    return String.format("Thing2: property2=%d", property2);
  }
}

class ArrayAsNullDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Thing2>
{
  @Override
  public Thing2 deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
  {
    JsonNode node = jp.readValueAsTree();
    if (node.isObject())
      return new ObjectMapper().setVisibility(JsonMethod.FIELD, Visibility.ANY).readValue(node, Thing2.class);
    return null;
  }
}
```

(You could make use of DeserializationConfig.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY to force the input to always bind to a collection, but that's probably not the approach I'd take given how the problem is currently described.)

Comment: Ok! Thanks, I kinda figured this was going to be the case...never can just be easy can it! Do you happen to know of a good tutorial on writing one?

Comment: no chance on fixing the original input, right? or, in the worst case, if that is the only case, what about a string replace from "[]" to "{}"

Comment: I wish I could, it's a web service call I have no control over, from a battlefield bad company 2 website.

Comment: > Do you happen to know of a good tutorial on writing one? -- Answer updated with example.

Comment: since jackson 2.5.0 you can use DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_ARRAY_AS_EMPTY_OBJECT

see @fabien reply

Answer (score 23):

Edit: Since Jackson 2.5.0, you can use DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_ARRAY_AS_EMPTY_OBJECT to resolve your problem.

The solution Bruce provides has a few problems/disadvantages:

- you'll need to duplicate that code for each type you need to deserialize that way
- ObjectMapper should be reused since it caches serializers and deserializers and, thus, is expensive to create. See http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonBestPracticesPerformance
- if your array contains some values, you probably want let jackson to fail deserializing it because it means there was a problem when it got encoded and you should see and fix that asap.

Here is my "generic" solution for that problem:

```
public abstract class EmptyArrayAsNullDeserializer<T> extends JsonDeserializer<T> {

  private final Class<T> clazz;

  protected EmptyArrayAsNullDeserializer(Class<T> clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz;
  }

  @Override
  public T deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
    ObjectCodec oc = jp.getCodec();
    JsonNode node = oc.readTree(jp);
    if (node.isArray() && !node.getElements().hasNext()) {
      return null;
    }
    return oc.treeToValue(node, clazz);
  }
}
```

then you still need to create a custom deserializer for each different type, but that's a lot easier to write and you don't duplicate any logic:

```
public class Thing2Deserializer extends EmptyArrayAsNullDeserializer<Thing2> {

  public Thing2Deserializer() {
    super(Thing2.class);
  }
}
```

then you use it as usual:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = Thing2Deserializer.class)
```

If you find a way to get rid of that last step, *i.e.* implementing 1 custom deserializer per type, I'm all ears ;)

Comment: This solution looks like what I need.. thanks.. however jackson is throwing a JsonMappingException: has no default (no arg) constructor when I try to use it. I've tried adding a default constructor to the base class but am not having any luck.

Comment: Make sure the class you pass to jackson to deserialize has a public default constructor (not just its base class). In the example above, i deserialize with Thing2.class; Thing2's class has a public default constructor.
Make sure all the sub-classes of the class you are trying to deserialize also have a public default constructor. In doubt, try with a simpler class with only primitive types and if it works you know it's a problem with one of your classes ;)

Answer (score 2):

There’s another angle to tackle this problem more generically for objects that would be deserialized using the BeanDeserializer, by creating a [`BeanDeserializerModifier`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/BeanDeserializerModifier.html) and registering it with your mapper. [`BeanDeserializerModifier`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/BeanDeserializerModifier.html) is a sort of alternative to subclassing `BeanDeserializerFactory`, and it gives you a chance to return something other than the normal deserializer that would be used, or to modify it.

So, first create a new `JsonDeserializer` that can accept another deserializer when it’s being constructed, and then holds on to that serializer. In the deserialize method, you can check if you’re being passed a `JsonParser` that's currently pointing at a  `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`. If you’re not passed `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`, then just use the default deserializer that was passed in to this custom deserialize when it was created.

Finally, make sure to implement `ResolvableDeserializer`, so that the default deserializer is properly attached to the context that your custom deserializer is using.

```java
class ArrayAsNullDeserialzer extends JsonDeserializer implements ResolvableDeserializer {
    JsonDeserializer<?> mDefaultDeserializer;

    @Override
    /* Make sure the wrapped deserializer is usable in this deserializer's contexts */
    public void resolve(DeserializationContext ctxt) throws JsonMappingException  {
         ((ResolvableDeserializer) mDefaultDeserializer).resolve(ctxt);
    }

    /* Pass in the deserializer given to you by BeanDeserializerModifier */
    public ArrayAsNullDeserialzer(JsonDeserializer<?> defaultDeserializer) {
        mDefaultDeserializer = defaultDeserializer;
    }

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonToken firstToken = jp.getCurrentToken();
        if (firstToken == JsonToken.START_ARRAY) {
            //Optionally, fail if this is something besides an empty array
           return null;
        } else {
            return mDefaultDeserializer.deserialize(jp, ctxt);
        }
    }
}
```

Now that we have our generic deserializer hook, let’s create a modifier that can use it. This is easy, just implement the `modifyDeserializer` method in your BeanDeserializerModifier. You will be passed the deserializer that *would* have been used to deserialize the bean. It also passes you the BeanDesc that will be deserialized, so you can control here whether or not you want to handle [] as null for all types.

```
public class ArrayAsNullDeserialzerModifier extends BeanDeserializerModifier  {

    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> modifyDeserializer(DeserializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc, JsonDeserializer<?> deserializer) {
        if ( true /* or check beanDesc to only do this for certain types, for example */ ) {
            return new ArrayAsNullDeserializer(deserializer);
        } else {
            return deserializer;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, you’ll need to register your BeanDeserializerModifier with your ObjectMapper. To do this, create a module, and add the modifier in the setup (SimpleModules don’t seem to have a hook for this, unfortunately). You can read more about modules elsewhere, but here’s an example if you don’t already have a module to add to:

```
Module m = new Module() {
    @Override public String getModuleName() { return "MyMapperModule"; }
    @Override public Version version() { return Version.unknownVersion(); }
    @Override public void setupModule(Module.SetupContext context) {
        context.addBeanDeserializerModifier(new ArrayAsNullDeserialzerModifier());
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers worked for me:

- We can't use a modifier since the `ObjectMapper` cannot be modified and we use a `@JsonDeserialize` annotation to install the deserializer.
- We don't have access to the `ObjectMapper` either.
- We need the resulting `Map` to be properly typed, which didn't seem to work with `ObjectCodec.treeToValue`.

This is the solution that finally worked:

```java
public class EmptyArrayToEmptyMapDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Map<String, SomeComplexType>> {
    @Override
    public Map<String, SomeComplexType> deserialize(JsonParser parser,
            DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
        if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JsonToken.START_ARRAY) {
            // Not sure what the parser does with the following END_ARRAY token, probably ignores it somehow.
            return Map.of();
        }
        return context.readValue(parser, TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructMapType(Map.class, String.class, SomeComplexType.class));
    }
}
```