# Jackson Parser: ignore deserializing for type mismatch

Tags: java, android, json, cakephp, jackson

I am getting following response generated from the server by `cakephp`

```
 [
 {
  "id": "42389",
  "start": "0000-00-00",
  "end": "0000-00-00",
  "event_id": null,
  "trip_id": "5791",
  "location_id": "231552",
  "user_id": "105",
  "users_attending": "0",
  "user_local": "0",
  "Trip": {
   "name": "Asdas"
  },
  "Event": [],
  "Location": {
   "name": "South Melbourne"
  }
 },
 {
  "id": "42392",
  "start": "0000-00-00",
  "end": "0000-00-00",
  "event_id": "1218",
  "trip_id": "4772",
  "location_id": "271505",
  "user_id": "105",
  "users_attending": "3",
  "user_local": "50",
  "Trip": {
   "name": "trip by 1059200"
  },
  "Event": {
   "title": "SampleEvent 454",
   "id": "1218"
  },
  "Location": {
   "name": "Houston"
  }
 },
 .......
 ]
```

The thing is that the parser expects `Event` object but if its `null` then it is receiving empty array.

Since the response is auto generated by `cakephp`, it has to be changed at a lot of places on server side.

Is there any simple way for jackson to ignore `Event` property if its an empty array??

EDIT:

I have tried having two properties with `Event` name: one array and other object but that too didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, I had to handle response like this for many objects I finally went ahead with creating a generic class which would return a `Deserializer` for a specific `class`.

Here is what I used

```
public class Deserializer<T> {

  public JsonDeserializer<T> getDeserializer(final Class<T> cls) {
      return new JsonDeserializer<T> (){

         @Override
         public T deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext arg1) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            JsonNode node = jp.readValueAsTree();
            if (node.isObject()) {
              return new ObjectMapper().convertValue(node, cls);
            }
            return null;
         }
     };
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I think it makes sense to separate it, if types are incompatible.

The other option would have been to use a common super-type, which would mean `java.lang.Object`, and you would get either `List` (for JSON array) or `Map` (for JSON Object). But would need to do post-processing to bind into concrete types.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Will try this approach too. I found another workaround by creating custom deserializer for `Event` object. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305565/jackson-deserialize-object-or-array) helped.

Comment: would using DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_INVALID_SUBTYPE as false also work for this case?

Comment: That only works for polymorphic types; so yes, if declared type uses polymorphic type handling (either via `@JsonTypeInfo`, or default typing). I am guessing it would not work well here.

Answer (score 0):

What I found the easiest solution to this problem was adding the feature:

```
DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_ARRAY_AS_NULL_OBJECT, true
```

to my objectmapper. Jackson does the rest for you. See https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html.

This answer gives an in depth explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22956168/9279756