# Jackson deserializing with custom deserializer causes a lot of GC calls and takes a lot longer

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

To solve my type mismatch problem discussed [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684808/jackson-parser-ignore-deserializing-for-type-mismatch/) I created custom `Deserializers` and added them to `ObjectMapper`. However the performance deteriorates significantly with this.

With default deserializer i get 1-2 Garbage collection calls in `logcat` while with custom deserializer there are at least 7-8 GC calls, and hence the processing time is also increase significantly.

My Deserializer :

```
public class Deserializer<T> {

public JsonDeserializer<T> getDeserializer(final Class<T> cls) {
  return new JsonDeserializer<T> (){

     @Override
     public T deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext arg1) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = jp.readValueAsTree();
        if (node.isObject()) {
          return new ObjectMapper().convertValue(node, cls);
        }
        return null;
     }
 };
}
}
```

And I am using this to add to Mapper

```
public class DeserializerAttachedMapper<T> {

   public ObjectMapper getMapperAttachedWith(final Class<T> cls , JsonDeserializer<T> deserializer) {
      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule(deserializer.toString(), new Version(1, 0, 0, null, null, null));
      module.addDeserializer(cls, deserializer);
      mapper.registerModule(module);
      return mapper;
   }
}
```

**EDIT:** Added extra data

My JSON is of considerable size but not huge:
I have pasted [it here](http://pastie.org/5170282)

Now for parsing the same JSON if i use this code:

```
   String response = ConnectionManager.doGet(mAuthType, url, authToken);
    FLog.d("location object response" + response);
  //        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("UserModule", new Version(1, 0, 0, null, null, null));
  //        JsonDeserializer<User> userDeserializer = new Deserializer<User>().getDeserializer(User.class);     
  //        module.addDeserializer(User.class, userDeserializer);

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  //        mapper.registerModule(module);
    JsonNode tree = mapper.readTree(response);
    Integer code = Integer.parseInt(tree.get("code").asText().trim());

    if(Constants.API_RESPONSE_SUCCESS_CODE == code) {
        ExploreLocationObject locationObject = mapper.convertValue(tree.path("response").get("locationObject"), ExploreLocationObject.class);
        FLog.d("locationObject" + locationObject);
        FLog.d("locationObject events" + locationObject.getEvents().size());
        return locationObject;
    }       
    return null;
```

Then my logcat is [like this](http://pastie.org/5170336)

But if I use this code for same JSON

```
        String response = ConnectionManager.doGet(mAuthType, url, authToken);
    FLog.d("location object response" + response);
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("UserModule", new Version(1, 0, 0, null, null, null));
    JsonDeserializer<User> userDeserializer = new Deserializer<User>().getDeserializer(User.class);

    module.addDeserializer(User.class, userDeserializer);
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(module);
    JsonNode tree = mapper.readTree(response);
    Integer code = Integer.parseInt(tree.get("code").asText().trim());

    if(Constants.API_RESPONSE_SUCCESS_CODE == code) {
        ExploreLocationObject locationObject = mapper.convertValue(tree.path("response").get("locationObject"), ExploreLocationObject.class);
        FLog.d("locationObject" + locationObject);
        FLog.d("locationObject events" + locationObject.getEvents().size());
        return locationObject;
    }       
    return null;
```

Then my logcat is [like this](http://pastie.org/5170352)

Comment: One additional comment: make absolutely sure you reuse `ObjectMapper` -- it is a heavy-weight object and should not be created once per request. Otherwise it could definitely cause lots of GC activity. Hard to know for sure from just code above.

Comment: Actually I noticed that your deserializer creates an ObjectMapper: this is very costly. You can avoid that by using `JsonParser.getCodec()`, casting result to `ObjectMapper` (which is safe upcast). That should help quite a bit too.

Comment: I modified my code and added object mapper to my singleton, the performance improved for default deserializer but the problem with custom deserializer is still there. Also, I noticed that if i add two deserializers to same module then the default deserializer gets called not the custom one.

The `JsonParser.getCodec()` isn't a static method , so I will have to create `JsonParser` for each request. won't that be expensive too??

Comment: Behavior of two deserializers sounds wrong; default one should only be called if there is no custom one for the type. On `JsonParser` -- should not create new one, but if you are in `deserialize(...)` method, you are passed one (not mapper). So all I am saying is that you can always find a mapper, iff you have `JsonParser` or `JsonGenerator` (that has reference; this is true if parser/generator was created by `ObjectMapper`).

Comment: just wanted to add that `Jsonparser.getCodec()` in deserializer results in `stackOverFlow` exception in this case, probably because it calls the same `deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext arg1)` method of the deserializer, resulting in infinite loop.

Answer (score 3):

How big is the object? Code basically builds a tree model (sort of dom tree), and that will take something like 3x-5x as much memory as the original document. So I assume your input is a huge JSON document.

You can definitely write a more efficient version using Streaming API. Something like:

```
JsonParser jp = mapper.getJsonFactory().createJsonParser(input);
JsonToken t = jp.nextToken();
if (t == JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
   return mapper.readValue(jp, classToBindTo);
}
return null;
```

it is also possible to implement this with data-binding (as `JsonDeserializer`), but it gets bit complicated just because you want to delegate to "default" deserializer.
To do this, you would need to implement `BeanDeserializerModifier`, and replace standard deserializer when "modifyDeserializer" is called: your own code can retain reference to the original deserializer and delegate to it, instead of using intermediate tree model.

Comment: I have edited my question and added the JSON, the parsing code and the logs. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are not tied to jackson you could also try Genson http://code.google.com/p/genson/.
In your case there are two main advantages: you will not loose in performance, it should be easier to implement. If the property event does not start with upper letter annotate it with @JsonProperty("Event") (same for the other properties starting with an upper letter).
With the following code you should be done:

```
Genson genson = new Genson.Builder()
            .withDeserializerFactory(new EventDeserializerFactory()).create();

YourRootClass[] bean = genson.deserialize(json, YourRootClass[].class);

class EventDeserializerFactory implements Factory<Deserializer<Event>> {

    public Deserializer<Event> create(Type type, Genson genson) {
        return new EventDeserializer(genson.getBeanDescriptorFactory().provide(Event.class,
                genson));
    }

}

class EventDeserializer implements Deserializer<Event> {
    private final Deserializer<Event> standardEventDeserializer;

    public EventDeserializer(Deserializer<Event> standardEventDeserializer) {
        this.standardEventDeserializer = standardEventDeserializer;
    }

    public Event deserialize(ObjectReader reader, Context ctx) throws TransformationException,
            IOException {
        if (ValueType.ARRAY == reader.getValueType()) {
            reader.beginArray().endArray();
            return null;
        }
        return standardEventDeserializer.deserialize(reader, ctx);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. will definitely give it a shot. But, atm I will first try improving performance with jackson.