# Jackson mapping Object or list of Object depending on json input

Tags: java, android, json, jackson, rest-client

I have this POJO :

```
public class JsonObj {

    private String id;
    private List<Location> location;


    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public List<Location> getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    @JsonSetter("location")
    public void setLocation(){
        List<Location> list = new ArrayList<Location>();
        if(location instanceof Location){
            list.add((Location) location);
            location = list;
        }
    }
}
```

the "location" object from the json input can be either a simple instance of Location or an Array of Location. When it is just one instance, I get this error :

```
Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of   START_OBJECT token
```

I've tried to implement a custom setter but it didn't work. How could I do to map either a Location or a List depending on the json input?

Comment: Different JSON means different JSON DTO. If your JSON has an `[]` you need to use `List`, if it has a `{}` you need a simple object.

Comment: It is sometimes [] and sometimes {} for the same key and unfortunally I can not change this.

Comment: Create a custom deserializer that checks if its a `[]` or a `{}` and appropriately creates a instance and adds it to the `List`.

Comment: It seems to be the solution. Could you provide some code or doc in order to help me implement this?

Comment: Just google `jackson deserializer`. Something like [this](http://pilhuhn.blogspot.ca/2013/07/custom-deserializer-in-jackson-and.html).

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm new to jackson mapping and I didn't succeed to create this deserializer. See my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21064003/jackson-custom-deserializer-mapping if you wish to help me. Thank you anyway!

Comment: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39041496/how-to-enforce-accept-single-value-as-array-in-jacksons-deserialization-process#answer-39043513) answer useful if you want to do this on a single property

Answer (score 25):

*Update: [Mher Sarkissian's soulution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41176461/1020871) works fine, it can also be used with annotations as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39043513/1020871), like so:.*

```
@JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
private List<Item> item;
```

---

My deepest sympathies for this most annoying problem, I had just the same problem and found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22956168/1020871

With a little modification I come up with this, first the generic class:

```
public abstract class OptionalArrayDeserializer<T> extends JsonDeserializer<List<T>> {

    private final Class<T> clazz;

    public OptionalArrayDeserializer(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException {
        ObjectCodec oc = jp.getCodec();
        JsonNode node = oc.readTree(jp);
        ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
        if (node.isArray()) {
            for (JsonNode elementNode : node) {
                list.add(oc.treeToValue(elementNode, clazz));
            }
        } else {
            list.add(oc.treeToValue(node, clazz));
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

And then the property and the actual deserializer class (Java generics is not always pretty):

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = ItemListDeserializer.class)
private List<Item> item;

public static class ItemListDeserializer extends OptionalArrayDeserializer<Item> {
    protected ItemListDeserializer() {
        super(Item.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this snippet, it solved my problem! Just in case [here is scala version of the code above](https://gist.github.com/Aivean/6bb90e3942f3bf966608).

Answer (score 5):

This is already supported by jackson

```
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
```