# Rest API Testing org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException

Tags: java, automated-tests, rest-assured

I am trying to test two Rest API Endpoints , one is a get and another is a post. The idea is that the response body returned by the get response shall be the body of the post.

Code that I am using:

```
RestAssured.baseURI = ROOT_URI;
RequestSpecification httpRequest = 
RestAssured.given().header("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedString);
String endPoint="/v1/getworkers";
Response response = httpRequest.request(Method.GET, endPoint);
String responseBody = response.getBody().asString();
```

Now the response body  that I am getting is :

```
{"workerDetails":
    [
    {"workerId":"TEST123456",
    "securityId":"TESTWORKERID",
    "workerStatus":"Active",
    "firstName":"Test",
    "lastName":"Userone"}
    ]
}
```

Now, I do the post request and put the String responseBody as the body:

```
RestAssured.baseURI = ROOT_URI;
String endpoint="/v1/PostWorkers";
RequestSpecification httpRequest = 
RestAssured.given().header("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedString)
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json").body(postbody);
Response response = httpRequest.request(Method.POST,endpoint);
String responseBody = response.getBody().asString();
```

And I am getting the error 400 :

> timestamp":1552670194453,"status":400,"error":"Bad
>   Request","exception":"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException","message":"JSON
>   parse error: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out
>   of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not
>   deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT
>   token\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@56bba771

What to do ?

Comment: Did you try the solution described here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/39043513/2387977

Comment: Whats the DTO you're trying to deserialize to?

Answer (score 1):

The issue according to the error log is:

> JSON parse error: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token

It means that the API is expecting an `ArrayList` as input, but is getting an `Object` as input instead. In other words, it would be expecting an input with `ArrayList<WorkerDetail>`, but you're passing an input of 
object `WorkerDetails`, which contains a field `workerDetails` of type `ArrayList<WorkerDetail>`.

Please try modifying the response of the get request from:

```
String responseBody = response.getBody().asString();
```

to:

```
List responseBody = response.jsonPath().getList("workerDetails");
```

Then pass this `responseBody` to the `body()` method on the `POST` request.

Comment: @supratimdutta did this help you?