# Java/Jackson Annotations: Mapping either an array or object?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

If I can get either of the following JSON bodies as responses:

```
{
   "error" : "some error",
   "code": 123
}
```

or

```
[
 {
    "name" : "name",
    "value" : "value"
 },
 {
    "name" : "name",
    "value" : "value"
 }
]
```

Is there a way to map either of these response to below Java POJO using annotations ?

```
public class Response {
    String error;
    int code;
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
}
```

Comment: for this you will need to have the success response array with key `nameValuePairs` - in this way `{"nameValuePairs" : [{"name" : "name", "value" : "value" }, ...]}`

Comment: @ShreyGarg yes, that's the problem...the external system is just returning an array...

Comment: After receiving the response, do you get it in the form of string?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, only the error response will deserialise. The issue is they are fundamentally different types - an object vs an array.

You can make it work with a custom module for jackson, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305565/jackson-deserialize-object-or-array)

Answer (score 0):

One possible response is a `JSON Object` and other is a `JSON Array`. In that case it is not possible to create one `POJO` class to handle it. Also, these two payloads means to different things: one is `SUCCESS` and other is `ERROR` payloads. In that case I would use [Facade design pattern](https://www.baeldung.com/java-facade-pattern) to create extra layer and hide this complex logic there. It could look like below:

```
class ResponseDeserialiserFacade {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public List<NameValuePair> deserialisePairs(String json) {
        try {
            return mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<NameValuePair>>() {
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                Error error = mapper.readValue(json, Error.class);
                throw new RequestApiException(error, e);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                throw new RequestApiException(Error.from("Can not parse: " + json), e1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you noticed I introduced new exception:

```
class RequestApiException extends RuntimeException {
    private final Error error;

    RequestApiException(Error error, Exception base) {
        super(base);
        this.error = error;
    }

    public Error getError() {
        return error;
    }
}
```

with `Error` class:

```
class Error {

    private String error;
    private String code;

    public static Error from(String message) {
        Error e = new Error();
        e.error = message;

        return e;
    }

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

Now we can test it for `SUCCESS` and `ERROR` payloads:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String success = "[\n" +
                "  {\n" +
                "    \"name\" : \"name\",\n" +
                "    \"value\" : \"value\"\n" +
                "  },\n" +
                "  {\n" +
                "    \"name\" : \"name\",\n" +
                "    \"value\" : \"value\"\n" +
                "  }\n" +
                "]\n";

        tryToParse(success);

        String error = "{\n" +
                "   \"error\" : \"some error\",\n" +
                "   \"code\": 123\n" +
                "}";
        tryToParse(error);
    }

    private static void tryToParse(String json) {
        ResponseDeserialiserFacade deserialiser = new ResponseDeserialiserFacade();
        try {
            List<NameValuePair> pairs = deserialiser.deserialisePairs(json);
            System.out.println("SUCCESS: " + pairs);
        } catch (RequestApiException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: " + e.getError());
        }
    }
}

class NameValuePair {

    private String name;
    private String value;

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

Above code prints:

```
SUCCESS: [NameValuePair{name='name', value='value'}, NameValuePair{name='name', value='value'}]
ERROR: Error{error='some error', code='123'}
```

As you can see, we treated error message like as exception.